# How to implement PDF download functionality in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, json

We are using the following code to download a PDF file:

```
router.get('/demo',function (req,res){ async function getinvoicelist(){
    var chunks = []; var options = { method: 'GET', url: 'https://api.fortnox.se/3/invoices/31/preview',
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

We are getting the following output when we console the body:

```
%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <</Length 1438/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream x��Y�r�6��+�Ɍ3S�xXڭ�h���IM���STB�n>�_�/p~!�^<H��N�xti���}��T�,��&k��g���xU|*҂�Gk�JPSH#13�װ�).�?�����`�������/��
```

[image: Console screenshot]

When we hit this, we want to route the PDF file download in browser with data. How can we do this?

Comment: Please format the code to improve readability, and add a more detailed explanation of what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

please follow `ES6` syntax now. Can you try it in browser once rather than Postman. Thanks.

Comment: i am trying in my browser but getting error when i console the api result then buffer format will show. but i want when hit this url then pdf file download in to my browser.